# Show Div's based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on one of the requirement, where I have to show div based on user input. Below is the code structure.

```
<input id="location-filter" type="text">

<div class="item">
   <div class="item-image">
      <a href="">
         <img class="img-fluid" src=""> 
         <div class="item-badges"></div>
         <div class="item-meta">
            <div class="item-price">
               <small></small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="item-info">
      <h3 class="item-title"><a href=""></a></h3>
      <div class="item-location">
         <i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
         <p>London</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-details-i"> 
         <span class="bedrooms" title="Bedrooms">3 <i class="fa fa-bed"></i></span>
         <span class="bathrooms" title="Bathrooms">2 <i class="fa fa-bath"></i></span>
         <span class="bathrooms" title="Car Space">1 <i class="fa fa-car"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="item-details">
         <p><a href="">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
   <div class="item-image">
      <a href="">
         <img class="img-fluid" src=""> 
         <div class="item-badges"></div>
         <div class="item-meta">
            <div class="item-price">
               <small></small>
            </div>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="item-info">
      <h3 class="item-title"><a href=""></a></h3>
      <div class="item-location">
         <i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
         <p>Canada</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item-details-i"> 
         <span class="bedrooms" title="Bedrooms">3 <i class="fa fa-bed"></i></span>
         <span class="bathrooms" title="Bathrooms">2 <i class="fa fa-bath"></i></span>
         <span class="bathrooms" title="Car Space">1 <i class="fa fa-car"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="item-details">
         <p><a href="">Read More</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are two 'item' divs, the difference is only 'item-location' div, containing p tag of location names. If user enters 'London', I want to show all 'item' divs which contain text 'london' and hide other 'item' divs. I tried the below code, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
$("#location-filter").keyup(function() {
// Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
var filter = $(this).val(),
count = 0;
// Loop through the div
$('.item > .item-location p').each(function() {
// If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
if ($("this").text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
$(this).hide();
// Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
} else {
$(this).show();
count++;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code had some mistakes. The `>` is used to select the direct child. `.item` has no `.item-location` element as direct child. That is why, `each` iterator wasn't running at all. Besides that, the `this` in the `if` condition is wrapped inside double quotes, making it a string. And the last mistake was that, in the `each` loop, `this` refers to the element being iterated. To hide or show the `.item`, you've to use `closest` to reach the ancestor `.item`

```js
$("#location-filter").keyup(function() {
  var filter = $(this).val(),
    count = 0;
  $('.item .item-location p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
      $(this).closest('.item').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).closest('.item').show();
      count++;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="location-filter" type="text">

<div class="item">
  <div class="item-image">
    <a href="">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="">
      <div class="item-badges"></div>
      <div class="item-meta">
        <div class="item-price">
          <small></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-info">
    <h3 class="item-title">
      <a href=""></a>
    </h3>
    <div class="item-location">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
      <p>London</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-details-i">
      <span class="bedrooms" title="Bedrooms">3 <i class="fa fa-bed"></i></span>
      <span class="bathrooms" title="Bathrooms">2 <i class="fa fa-bath"></i></span>
      <span class="bathrooms" title="Car Space">1 <i class="fa fa-car"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-details">
      <p><a href="">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item">
  <div class="item-image">
    <a href="">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="">
      <div class="item-badges"></div>
      <div class="item-meta">
        <div class="item-price">
          <small></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item-info">
    <h3 class="item-title">
      <a href=""></a>
    </h3>
    <div class="item-location">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker "></i>
      <p>Canada</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-details-i">
      <span class="bedrooms" title="Bedrooms">3 <i class="fa fa-bed"></i></span>
      <span class="bathrooms" title="Bathrooms">2 <i class="fa fa-bath"></i></span>
      <span class="bathrooms" title="Car Space">1 <i class="fa fa-car"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-details">
      <p><a href="">Read More</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great. Don't forget to mark answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your CSS selector in the Jquery.

```
$('.item  .item-location p')
```

should be right. This is because with the arrow, it is looking for an element with "item-location" directly under an element with the class "item" which it is not able to find.

Comment: Take a look at my answer :)